# Why is there static in my Hyper-V Virtual Machine's sound output?

Tags: audio, windows-10, hyper-v

I have a Windows 10 64-bit virtual machine running on a Windows 10 64-bit host machine.

When the virtual machine outputs sound, "static" or crackling noises can be heard.

The host machine is using a USB audio interface.

How can I fix this problem so that the virtual machine's sound is clear?